# Locating created file with Java EE and Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, file-io

I have created a dynamic web project, and use Apache Tomcat as a server.

In my servlet I'm creating a text file and want to reuse that in a JSP. However they are by default created in the installation folder of Eclipse when I do something as simple as the following:

```
File f = new file("test.txt").
```

I don't know why this happens. Is there a way to create the file in the `WebContent` directory as I want to make that file available for download in my JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a concept of the "current directory". When you start an application via Eclipse, this may indeed point to your installation directory. If you don't specify any path, a file will be created in this current directory. Hence the reason why your `test.txt` ends up there.

The `WebContent` directory is a something that is specific to Eclipse. Your code should not depend on putting anything there. You only start your application via Eclipse when you're developing it, not when you're deploying it to a live server.

The content of this directory will become the `root` of your .war, which is a well known location independent of how you start & deploy you app, BUT you still cannot depend on writing anything to this location at run-time. You might deploy your application as a packaged .war (likely for live deployments) or you may deploy your application unpackaged but then your application server may simply not pick up any changes done at run-time.

What you can do if you are sure your application only runs on a single server is writing the files to a well known location on your file system, such as `/tmp`, or `/var/yourapp/files`, etc. The code serving up those files can then pick them up from that location.

If you want to play it 100% safe according to the Java EE rules, you'd store your files on something like an FTP server that has a configurable address. Technically your war could be shipped between nodes on a cluster and requests could end up going to different machines, so depending on a local filesystem wouldn't work then.

Answer (score 0):

Executing this statement `this.getServletContext().getRealPath ("")`, you'll obtain the path where Tomcat WebServer is pointing at at runtime. You could add a folder "MyFolder" and call this statement:

new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath ("") + "/MyFolder/test.txt");

Anyway, the default path looks something like:

```
...\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\<NameOfYourProject>
```

Note that when you create a new file, it won't appear in your immediate workspace (check the *.metadata* path), unless you change the runtime location tomcat should point at.